# UNION ALL & VIEWS

Tags: sql, t-sql, view

Consider a view consisting of dozens of views (let's call them z_views) connected to each other by union all. When we run this query and we get an error message for any reason, is there a method to find out which z_view this error code belongs to?

```
SELECT [BEYN TESCİL NO-KALEM NO] AS TESNO_KALNO , ACIKLAMA as ACIKLAMA FROM ABD_EMY_2 --zview1


UNION ALL
SELECT TESNO_KALNO , ACIKLAMA as ACIKLAMA FROM ALICI_SATICI_ILISKISI --z_view2


UNION ALL
SELECT TESNO_KALNO , ACIKLAMA as ACIKLAMA FROM ANTIDAMPING -- z_view3
```

Comment: Since the query is optimized as a whole, there's no guarantee that the final execution plan even contains nodes that distinctly represent individual views. So in short, no.

Comment: Nested views is a well documented anti-pattern and should be avoided where possible, it makes it much harder for the optimizer to find a good plan. There is no information in your question about what error you are seeing which makes this impossible to answer.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't. Best practice in this case is to understand errors and try to fix them or write logic that handles them.

You need to check every view separately.

You don’t have any information about the errors in your post.